# react js, when open page Other than home in new tab show 404

Tags: reactjs

I load url http://reactnext.mohan21.ir and show my project but when I open http://reactnext.mohan21.ir/about in new tab it shows a 404 error. How do I solve this error?

Comment: always provide code to help others understand better what the actual problem is

Answer (score 1):

you can use `react-router-dom` to switch components based on URL

so for example, if you have 2 pages, **home** and **about**, then you put everything related to home page in a component names **Home** or anything you would prefer, and another component for **about** page, then in your `App` component, you can use something like this:

```js
import {Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import HomePage from "path/to/homepage"
import AboutPage from ""path/to/aboutpage""

export default function App(){
  return (<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
      <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router />
)
}
```

- `Router` is setting up the environment to help you take advantage of routing.
- `Switch` is decide which route to render based on the `Route`'s in its children.
- `Route` defines properties to help `Switch` choose a component to render based on the URL of the browser.

You can learn more about react router here https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

Comment: i used nextJS, when click other page from home show correctly but when other page reload show 404, please go to http://reactnext.mohan21.ir

Comment: you mentioned reactjs, that is why I provided that answer, because react doesn't have an opinion about routing, but nextjs does, next js assumes each JS/JSX file inside page folder an independent page, do you use it that way ?

pages ---
            |
            --- index.jsx
            |
            --- about.jsx

Comment: its interesting, do you have the code online, on github or somewhere so I can take a look?

Comment: https://github.com/mohan-21/rc -- nextJs remove and add react-router-dom

Comment: I ran the app and works very well, you changed it to react application tho.

Comment: do you run [link](http://reactnext.mohan21.ir/about) without 404 error in host?

Comment: nope, that link still gives me 404, but I think the problem is with your hosting mechanism, because on localhost it works OK, but on production it gives 404, which most probably means that you don't redirect all requests to index.html,  basically react-router-dom requires you to redirect all requests comes to your server to index.html, so that package can interfere and use changed URL to render different content, take a look at https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/

Answer (score 1):

i used htaccess and run without 404

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```